# Keyboard shortcut for GitHub saved replies

Tags: github

Since March 29th, 2016, GitHub has supported "saved replies," for things like signatures, code reviews, issue reports, and so on. Is there a keyboard shortcut to insert saved replies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of March 2nd 2018 this is now possible:

[image: saved replies shortcuts]

> https://blog.github.com/2018-03-02-saved-replies-keyboard-shortcuts/

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way for you to use keyboard shortcuts to do that. You can check keyboard shortcuts on a page by pressing <kbd>?</kbd>.

As shown below, this is the only way to use the GitHub saved replies.

[image]

You can, however, use [TextExpander](https://textexpander.com/) instead :)